# Trouble filling in oval shape with type

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to make a somewhat interesting layout for a design course and I'm having trouble.

I'm trying to do this:

[image]

But I want mine to be the number 8 filled with type. So a simple explanation would be I want to fill the shape of a Helvetica Neue "8" with multiple lines of type. I've tried using compound path, but it doesn't seem to be working with the oval holes in the shape of the letter(number).

This is the result I get after trying Object>Expand>Object>Compound path> Release: [image]

I'm a bit stuck and I'm wondering what could be done here. I've tried multiple workarounds, but it turns out my illustrator expertise is insufficient.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since *Area Type* tool doesn't work on Compound paths, you can use *Text Wrap* feature in Illustrator.

1. Simply release the compound path.
2. Group those two circles in a new layer and hide them temporarily.
   You'll have this:

[image]

3. Use *Area Type* tool to type/paste your text for the solid 8 shape

[image]

4. Then unhide those two circles group and select it and go to `Object > Text Wrap > Make`. You should get the result you need.

[image]

If you go to `Object > Text Wrap > Text Wrap Options`, you can decrease the offset so you get a shape similar to the original shape of 8 before typing text inside it.

[image]

Note that you'll still have those white colored circles. You may need a workaround (like changing color) depending on your background.

Comment: its excellent, am trying to practise, but my '8' doesn't want to release the compound path.

Comment: I took an eight, selected, went to object, but the compound is greyed out! why @vikas

Comment: @SuraiyaAbedin you have to convert it into a shape first. It's a text.

Comment: by expanding it?

Comment: @SuraiyaAbedin yes! Expand or go to Type > Create outlines

Comment: I always forget to tag :/

Comment: Thank you  :) @vikas

Comment: @SuraiyaAbedin tag is not necessary when you're commenting on an answer. the one who wrote it will get notified

Comment: And I think you can't even tag here. Can you?

Comment: facepalm, okay, i will remember this

Comment: yes, i can tag you, by putting an @ sign before your name

Comment: @SuraiyaAbedin show me

Comment: Try tagging in the beginning of sentence. Use captial V.

Comment: (can you see.......)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127897/discussion-between-vikas-and-suraiya-abedin).

Comment: oh no! where is your name? it's gone. I put an @ before VIKAS